# backbone template большой обьем данных

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

Не могу понять  как  с помошью  backbone и шаблонизатора от underscore вывести массив данных . вывод 1 ного набора понятен . а вот массив  что то я не поиму .

Как вывести Newdefaults ?

```js
var testModel  = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        name:'иван',
        age:40,
        job:'слесарь'
    },
    Newdefaults:{
        1:{ name:'Иван',age:40,job:'слесарь'},
        2:{ name:'Иван2',age:23,job:'слесарь'},
        3:{ name:'Иван3',age:21,job:'слесарь'},
        4:{ name:'Иван3',age:32,job:'слесарь'},
        5:{ name:'Иван4',age:40,job:'слесарь'},
        6:{ name:'Иван5',age:34,job:'слесарь'},
        7:{ name:'Иван6',age:26,job:'слесарь'},
        8:{ name:'Иван7',age:21,job:'слесарь'},
        9:{ name:'Иван8',age:22,job:'слесарь'},
        10:{ name:'Иван9',age:22,job:'слесарь'},
        11:{ name:'Иван12',age:26,job:'слесарь'}

    }
});

var testView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName:"div",
    id:'testBlock',
    events:{
        'click #search_bot':"serachBottom"
    },
    template: _.template('<strong><%= name %></strong> ( <%= age %> ) - <%= job %>'),
    initialize:function(){
        this.render();
    },
    render:function(){
        //this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
        //return this;
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        //$('#testBlock').html(view.el);
    },
    serachBottom:function(){
        console.log('work it');
    }
});
var model = new testModel();
var  view = new testView({ model:model });
$('#testBlock').html(view.el);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоватся самым обыкновенным циклом for -

```js
const Newdefaults = {
      1:{ name:'Иван',age:40,job:'слесарь'},
      2:{ name:'Иван2',age:23,job:'слесарь'},
      3:{ name:'Иван3',age:21,job:'слесарь'},
      4:{ name:'Иван3',age:32,job:'слесарь'},
      5:{ name:'Иван4',age:40,job:'слесарь'},
      6:{ name:'Иван5',age:34,job:'слесарь'},
      7:{ name:'Иван6',age:26,job:'слесарь'},
      8:{ name:'Иван7',age:21,job:'слесарь'},
      9:{ name:'Иван8',age:22,job:'слесарь'},
      10:{ name:'Иван9',age:22,job:'слесарь'},
      11:{ name:'Иван12',age:26,job:'слесарь'}
}

document.body.innerHTML = _.template(`
<% for(var def of Newdefaults) { %> 
  <strong><%= def.name %></strong> ( <%= def.age %> ) - <%= def.job %> </br>
<% } %>
`)({Newdefaults: Object.values(Newdefaults)});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: неажиданно . Спасибо.